# Indicating case for proper nouns

Tags: noun, grammatical-case, article, proper-noun

Consider sentences of the form (correct me if I've got them wrong):

> **Mir** ist langweilig / Es ist **mir** langweilig.
>
> **Dem** Mann ist kalt / Es ist **dem** Mann kalt.

It's important **not** to use the nominative form (*ich*) for these pronouns as that would change the meaning of the sentences completely.

But what if the nouns in question are proper nouns / nouns without articles (which don't have any case markers)? How would it look then?

I did find the adjective *gelangweilt* that presumably could be used with a nominative noun, but I don't want to "cop out" and rephrase.

How would I indicate the dative case of a proper noun in this case without rephrasing (e.g. ***zu / nach** John ist es langweilig*)? Also, how does German solve such problems in the general case?

Comment: _John ist gelangweilt_ and _John friert [es]_ are the better, unambiguous alternatives to _John ist langweilig_ and _John ist kalt_. Some dialects allow articles before some kinds of proper names, as in _dem John ist langweilig_ and _dem John ist kalt_. Also, _es ist mir langweilig_ and _es ist dem Mann kalt_ are unidiomatic.

Comment: @Crissov: Very interesting; please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*John ist gelangweilt* and *John friert* (dialectal: *John friert es*) are better, unambiguous alternatives to *John ist langweilig* (‘boring’ ./. ‘bored’) and *John ist kalt* (‘cold’ ./. ‘freezing’).

Some dialects, e.g. Ripuarian, allow articles before certain kinds of proper names, as in *dem John ist langweilig* and *dem John ist kalt*. Elsewhere, this sounds **very** wrong.

Also, the *es* in *es ist mir langweilig* and *es ist dem Mann kalt* is unidiomatic, although you could say *Lesen ist mir zu langweilig* or *das Eis ist dem Mann zu kalt* and substitute the pronoun as in *ich habe das Buch nicht fertiggelesen, es ist mir zu langweilig* and *das Eis kommt direkt aus der Gefriertruhe, es ist dem Mann zu kalt*.

Answer (score 2):

> But what if the nouns in question are proper nouns / nouns without articles (which don't have any case markers)? How would it look then?

Do you mean something like *Peter ist langweilig?*

Yes, this is ambiguous, meaning you'll have to decide from context whether Peter is bored or boring.

> Also, how does German solve such problems in the general case?

Why, context of course.

Answer (score 1):

*John ist langweilig* seems to be used differently. I've never encountered that sentence with the meaning of "He's bored", but only in the sense of "He's boring".
In other German-speaking parts, however, it seems to be valid to mean both; particularly in regions where they also use the word *fad*, meaning *langweilig*. So we're talking about Southern Germany and Austria here.

So, to be on the safe side, I'd recommend to change it a bit:

> John ist gelangweilt.
>   John ist's langweilig.

Both are possible. The former certainly is more common, but I wouldn't dismiss the second one.

Regarding *kalt*, I'd say

> John hat kalt.

but this is also restricted to certain regions. That said, I've found some statements on the Internet that this phrasing is even used in Switzerland, so it seems to be quite widespread.

Comment: So from your second example, can I take it that "Es ist John langweilig" is also acceptable and means he is bored? Also, is a construction with *zu* or *nach* possible with *langweilig* to suggest boredom?

Comment: "Es ist John langweilig" sounds very odd. Not sure if anyone would say it like that, but I'd go with "John ist es langweilig" only. – Frankly speaking I don't unerstand the "zu"/"nach" question. However, if you'd say "Nach John ist es langweilig" it would mean "According to John, it's boring".

Comment: _[I]n theory [John ist langweilig] could mean that he's bored, but that's not the way it is used._

Says who? It's definitely used in everyday speech, particularly with the colloquial expression "fad", which otherwise behaves identical to "langweilig".

Comment: @Ingmar Then this is regional thing. Never heard it with that other meaning. Furthermore, "fad" is a word I hear very rarely.

Comment: It's frequently used down here. Yes, I am from Austria.